# Usando Console.ReadLine() no WriteLine()

Tags: c#, .net, console

O usuário digitou assim no console:

> ```
> adicionartempo;(qualquer número que ele digitou)
> ```

```
string adicionartempo = Console.ReadLine();
```

Depois de digitar isto, como posso fazer para pegar o número que ele digitou e digitar no Console.WriteLine? Deste jeito:

```
Console.WriteLine("O tempo (numero que ele digitou) foi adicionado")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce tem que converter o valor para inteiro, veja:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int tempo = 0;
        
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempo))            
            Console.WriteLine("O tempo {0} foi adicionado", tempo);            
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("Valor inteiro inválido");
    }
}
```

Entrada:

> 10

Saída:

> O tempo 10 foi adicionado

O método `TryParse` faz isso para você.

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/me186g).

## Edição

Depois de esclarecer a dúvida do AP [no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68569/discussion-between-betadarknight-and-gato) elaborei esta solução:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Comando: ");
        
        var comando = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (VerrificarComando(comando))
        {
            var tempo = 0;
            
            if (int.TryParse(Regex.Match(comando, @"\d+").Value, out tempo))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O tempo {0} foi adicionado", tempo);
                
                return;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Valor inteiro inválido");
        }        
        
        Console.WriteLine("Comando inválido");
    }
    
    static bool VerrificarComando(string comando)
    {                    
        return Regex.Match(comando, @"\b(adicionartempo)\b").Success;
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wOMMb5).

Comment: Tem como ser nesse formato?: adicionartempo;(qualquer número que ele digitou) No caso a pessoa teria que digitar adicionartempo; antes de digitar o número

Comment: @BetaDarkNight vc quer uma função, tipo `AdicionarTempo()`?

Comment: Não, a pessoa teria que digitar adicionartempo; antes de digitar o número para que seja executado

Comment: @BetaDarkNight como se fosse um tipo de opção?

Comment: Sim, exemplo: adicionartempo1;(tempo 1), adicionartempo2;(tempo 2) e por assim vai

Comment: @BetaDarkNight da uma olhada, editei a resposta.

Comment: Não teria como colocar tudo junto? Quando escrever o adicionartempo;tempo já adicionar o tempo?

Comment: Mas o tempo é informado pelo usuário ou é um valor aleatório?

Comment: Informado pelo usuário

Comment: Mas é isso q o programa faz, o usuário digita o comando adicionartempo e em seguida informa o tempo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68569/discussion-between-betadarknight-and-gato).

Answer (score 2):

O jeito certo de fazer isso é assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Digite o ID do artista:");
        if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero)) WriteLine($"O tempo {numero} foi adicionado");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iYyJJH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ym0xb3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/BasicRead.cs).

Comment: Tem como ser nesse formato?: adicionartempo;(qualquer número que ele digitou) No caso a pessoa teria que digitar adicionartempo; antes de digitar o número